# Angular apps route throwing is not a function error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have this spring app where I got a view, controller for it in .js and then routes for it:

The app.js where I show the route.

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/myObjects/:objectId', {
            templateUrl: '/objects/object-more.html',
            controller: 'ObjectMoreCtrl'
        })
});
```

Now the ObjectMoreCtrl.js is also created, it exists and it's contents are right. The problem here is that when this route code is executed, it will redirect to the url that `templateUrl` show, but at the controller step it will throw this error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ObjectMoreCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

So what is the problem here? How come my ObjectMoreCtrl is undefined?

Comment: Can provide more info if needed.

Comment: If I look at the network tab in chrome dev console, the ObjectMoreCtrl is never even loaded, no 403 or anything for it.

Comment: Fixed by re-installing angular.

Answer (score 0):

dont you thing that is missing the otherwise({...});?

```
...
.otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/anyWhere'
        });
...
```

Comment: I only provided the .when, I have the .otherwise stated out too of course. I got the problem actully fixed by just reinstalling angular. Seemed to be some sort of a bug.